# Javascript get and format current date

Tags: javascript, date, format

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Formatting a date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

I need to show a **current date** in format like this (some examples):

```
sep 10, 2012
nov 5, 2012
```

and so on.

Using `javascript` I get a current date object

```
var date  = new Date();
```

what I need to do next?

Comment: Have you seen [Formatting a date in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript)?

Comment: Please use the search feature before asking a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this.

```
function dateTest(){
  var d =new Date();
 var month_name=new Array(12);
 month_name[0]="Jan"
 month_name[1]="Feb"
 month_name[2]="Mar"
 month_name[3]="Apr"
 month_name[4]="May"
 month_name[5]="Jun"
 month_name[6]="Jul"
 month_name[7]="Aug"
 month_name[8]="Sep"
 month_name[9]="Oct"
 month_name[10]="Nov"     
 month_name[11]="Dec"
 alert(month_name[d.getMonth()]+" "+d.getDate()+" , "+d.getFullYear());
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use dateFormat lib available in following link
http://stevenlevithan.com/assets/misc/date.format.js

Refer this article for formatting js using above lib.
http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

Edit:
If you cant use lib then

> var d = new Date();
>
> var curr_date = d.getDate();
>
> var curr_month = d.getMonth();
>
> var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
>
> var formattedDate = curr_date + " " + curr_month + ", " + curr_year;

Comment: There's [moment.js](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10119138/399317) too, it got lots of upvotes on the other question.

Comment: I cannot use any third party libraries

Answer (score 1):

You can use the getMonth (including some switch/case for the text), the getDate and the getFullYear methods to build your string.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/prototype#Methods

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

You can use this function in your code :

```
function getFormattedDate(input){
   var pattern=/(.*?)\/(.*?)\/(.*?)$/;
   var result = input.replace(pattern,function(match,p1,p2,p3){
   var months=['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Dec'];
   return (months[(p1-1)]+" "+p2<10?"0"+p2:p2)+" "+p3;
});
alert(result);
}
```

And for ref. you can call this function directly like this:

```
getFormattedDate("11/18/2013");
```

OR you can use this code, too.

```
var date  = new Date();
dateFormat(date,"mediumDate");
```

you can also find further different formats [here.](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format)

Comment: new Date().format doesnt exist in standard javascript

Comment: @Hugo Thanks for your alert. I have updated it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function getCurrentDate(){
var now=new Date();
var date=now.getDate();
var year=now.getFullYear();
var months=new Array('jan', 'feb', 'mar' ... 'dec');
var month=months[now.getMonth()]

return month + ' ' + date + ', ' + year;
}
```