# Executing PHP code in a *.html file

Tags: php

This is an example code.
In my `.html` file, I am using following HTML + PHP-code:

```
Today is: <? print(Date("l F d, Y")); ?>.
```

I would expect to see:

```
Today is: monday October 4, 2010.
```

The only thing I see is:

```
Today is:.
```

(mind the dot at the end).

This means the PHP-code is not processed!

PHP-code in a .php file works fine.

I tried to add  `AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html` and `addtype application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .inc .html` to the `.htaccess` file, neither of which helped.

Is there something wrong with my hosting-provider? (on Apache server) Or am making some mistake?
Please help, as I am puzzling for many days now.

Comment: Change `<?` to `<?php`. Short tags are a setting that is not enabled on every host

Comment: Or to `<?=` and lose the `print`; `<?=` always works, irregardless of the short_open_tag setting.

Comment: You say HTML page, so in a .html page will the <? or <?php work? But in any case you can try DarkBee's solution.

Comment: And if that does not work just save your page as `.php` as well. There is not need to store files as  `.html` as PHP will return the html as html

Comment: Php code can only run inside a .php extension file. However you can use htaccess to rewrite .php url to .html

Comment: @madforstrength Well he tried to change the filehandler for html to php but dunno if this works on a shared host

Comment: ya i used "<?php" only bt not working

Comment: @madforstrength php code can run regardless of the file's extension if server is configured properly.

Comment: no no its not working here.

Comment: file extension is .html @rakesh shetty

Comment: @Rakesh so change it with .php because your trying to run PHP code in .html extension which is not right. rename your file with .php extension

Comment: @Rakesh i can make work in `javascript`

Comment: actually that .html file is included in many files

Comment: @Rakesh either you can rename the file or if you dont want to then you can use javascript/jQuery to display today's date

Comment: i want to print the message which is coming in url as a alert here

Comment: @Rakesh you want to `print the message which is coming in the url`? Where did you mentioned this in your question? Please explain in detail what exactly you want to do

Comment: its ok now iam asking it. answer it if u can

Comment: @Rakesh this not the way how stackoverflow work. If you want the answer then ask properly with details. This make confuse for other users, people here will not read your mind. Either you edit your question or ask different question

Comment: @Rakesh **if you need to run php in `.html` file then instead `.html` type `.rakesh` it will work** [click here to know more](http://www.codeconquest.com/website/client-side-vs-server-side/)
-------

Comment: @sanoj better u type ur name and run then it will work for sure

Answer (score 0):

Save your file `.html` file with extension `.php`

For example if your file name is `sample.html` rename it to **`sample.php`**

And on sample.php file write the following code :

```
<?php

  echo "Today is: ".date("l F d, Y");

?>
```

Output : `Today is: Tuesday December 30, 2014`

See here [**DEMO**](https://eval.in/238341)

**Edit :-** If you don't want to use PHP then you can display current date using Javascript. See **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513144/javascript-get-and-format-current-date)** for javascript solution

Answer (score 0):

**Since you need to Display data ONLY using html page**

So only way is using `javascript`

```
<span id="time"></span>

var today = new Date();
 document.getElementById('time').innerHTML=today;
```

### [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n2XB6/59/)

Comment: This isn't quite right. HTML still comes from the server, and is processed by Apache before sending it to the client. You can configure Apache to send the `.html` document via the PHP parser prior to being sent to the client if you wish ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295141/server-not-parsing-html-as-php)).

Comment: @halfer thats right but `html` can run in localhost without server but `php` can't it need a server to run

Comment: Sure, but the OP mentions a "hosting provider" and "Apache", so we can assume they have those.

Comment: @halfer thats right but i just mention that `php` code will not run in `.html` files as you commented then let me remove that line :)

Comment: PHP won't run in HTML files _by default_. But it can be configured to do so, and that appears to be what the OP wants. See the `AddType` Apache directives in the question.

Comment: @halfer by configured we can make php run in `.html` ?? then i have to learn about that, thanks for teaching

Comment: than what would be wrong after configured  still no output

Comment: Possibly the `.htaccess` file is not being read by Apache. Also there are different ways of running PHP, and perhaps it needs a different directive to enable the PHP engine for this file extension. Difficult to say without being able to try things, to be honest.

Comment: to be honest i don't have any knowledge about `.htaccess` where can i learn about that online

Comment: @sanoj: if u dont hav any knowledge on htaccess, just keep calm.dont give wrong answers

Comment: @halfer: thanx a lot halfer for ur valuable answer:)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using php use javascript like this,

```
<button type="button"
   onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = Date()">
   Click me to display Date</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```